# Animating a zoomScale on UIScrollView with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Relatively new to iOS apps, and swift, so I'm a little lost on how to proceed.

Basically, I have a UIImageView, and i'm able to pinch to zoom/scroll, as my UIImageView is in a UIScrollView, but I'd like to add a double tap on the UIImage to zoom in as well.

I'm able to zoom in (just set the zoomScale to 3.0 for now), but I'd like to have a smooth transition. I did see the zoom(to:, animated:) method, but I wasn't quite sure on how to zoom into the center of the view.

Anyways, here's what I have thus far.

I've created the tapGestureRecognizer, and assigned it to the UIImageView

```
 let tapGesture =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapImageViewGesture))        
    self.Image1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.Image1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

and below is the function to perform the zoom

```
func tapImageViewGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Touched")
    self.pinchZoomScroll1.zoomScale = 3.0

}
```

Is there a simple way I can have some sort of a smooth animation of zooming in?, or should I go with using the zoom function instead, as it already supports animation?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried `self.pinchZoomScroll1.setZoomScale(3.0, animated: true)` ?

Comment: that works, I must have overlooked that function. Thank you! (if you put the answer below, i'll accept it.

Comment: Please write an answer yourself. I usually post an answer only when I can confirm in my env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can set set animation true by using this :

```
self.pinchZoomScroll1.setZoomScale(3.0, animated: true)
```

or you can also use scrollView delegate func by setting scrollViewminimumScale and max scale:

```
 pinchZoomScroll1.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
 pinchZoomScroll1.maximumZoomScale = 6.0 

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

return Image1
}
```

Comment: +1 for the first part (`setZoomScale`), this is the actual answer and still works the same way in Swift 5/Xcode 12.4. I'm not sure how the second part applies to the question though because it just explains how to set up the image view for scrolling but doesn't explain an alternative way of how to do the "scroll with an animation" part op asked for (he said that "pinch to zoom" already works, so he has to be using a delegate already).